# How to update Laravel queue workers' running code in a docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, supervisord

I have a Laravel instance running inside a docker container. I also have supervisord keeping some queue workers running.
In my `Dockerfile`,  I have this:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

`supervisord.conf` includes other config files, including `laravel-worker.conf` which looks like this:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
directory=/var/www
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=950
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=www-data
numprocs=20
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/logs/queue-worker-error.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=524288
stderr_logfile=/var/www/logs/queue-worker-error.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=524288
stopwaitsecs=3600
priority=6
```

I have another `.conf` file that runs this bash script:

```sh
while true
do
    php /var/www/artisan schedule:run --no-interaction &
    sleep 60
done
```

I don't know if any of that code is relevant. My problem is that when I update my PHP code, the jobs keep trying to use old code. I tried the following:

- restarting the workers using `php artisan queue:restart`
- `php artisan queue:flush`
- restarting the container using `docker restart <container>`
- removing the container and image and rebuilding them

Now I don't know what to try, and I'm annoyed. What should I try next?

Comment: How do you update the code? PHP won't reload the code during the execution, so you at least need to stop the worker completely

Comment: @NicoHaase What do you mean? Stop it how? That's what I want to know. `php artisan queue:restart` was an attempt to do just that

Comment: Would `queue:restart` also affect the process that is triggered through supervisord? If even rebuilding the container did not help, I would assume that you should search anywhere else for the problem, as this sounds like building the image itself does not work properly